# Understand regular expressions?

Tags: regex, xml, rest, web, regular-language

I am trying to understand regular expressions. I am trying to parse data from XML web service using regular expressions. I need your help to understand few regular expressions.

Regular expressions that I need to understand.

1: https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=ac%5C%2Fdc //What this 'ac%5C%2Fdc' regular expression in query means?

2: http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/area/?query=%22%C3%8Ele-de-France%22 //What this '%22%C3%8Ele-de-France%22' regular expression in query means?

Comment: 1) Don't parse XML with regex 2) Your two examples aren't regular expression but URL.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that they are not regular expressions. Actually, query supports 'Lucene Search Syntax' that also supports regular expressions that's why I became confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not regular expressions.

Check on `urlencode()` and  `urldecode()` from PHP to see more clearly your url

https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode/
https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urldecode/

Then, we can't explain you how works the back-end of this website, but basically we can see that it's just basics `contains` or `equals` query

http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/area/?query=%22Rhone-Alpes%22
Will return all musics with `Rhone-Alpes` mentioned

http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/area/?query=Rhone-Alpes
Will return all musics with `Rhone` or `Alpes`

Comment: What is meant by %22, %C3, %2Fdc?

Comment: Those are some characters converted in HEX by `urlencode()` go check on this website https://www.asciitable.com/
For example, `%22` means `"`